# How can I register a manufacturer code to be used in AU app extensions?

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio, audiounit, ios-app-extension

The links for registering a manufacturer code seem to redirect to a page that doesn't offer any registration possibilities.

http://developer.apple.com/datatype/

The link is from the Audio Unit Development fundamentals, stating that *Apple expects each developer to register a manufacturer code, as a “creator code,“ on the Data Type Registration page.*

And information on the subject seems rather scarce.
Does anyone know how one is supposed to get a value that can be incorporated into a new Audio Unit project?

Many thanks!